# Phone Gap [error] cmd: Command failed with exit code 8

Tags: android, windows, node.js, cordova

I'm new to "phonegap" I've just installed all necessary tools at my Win7 x64 PC in order to get it running for my first android app (following the installation at http://phonegap.com/install)

--> Every help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!!

After following the commands

> 1. npm install -g phonegap
> 2. phonegap create myapp
> 3. phonegap build local android

**I keep getting the following error msg in cdm:**

```
    E:\Android development\nodejs\mmiapp>phonegap local build android
    [phonegap] adding the Android platform...

    C:\Users\Reen\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
    Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add ed to your path.
        at C:\Users\Reen\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:47:27

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:651:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:968:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
    { [Error: C:\Users\Reen\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8] code: 8 }
    [error] C:\Users\Reen\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
```

These are my app/program directories:

```
    Nodejs: E:\Android development\nodejs
    AndroidSDk: E:\Android development\sdk
    Workspace: E:\Android development\Workspace
    Eclipse: E:\Android development\eclipse
    Git: E:\Android development\nodejs\package\Git
    Apache ant: C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4
    Java JDK: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
    cordova: C:\Users\Reen\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib
```

Following the Win7 environment variables(**User variable "User"**:)

```
    "Android_Home": E:\Android development\sdk
    "SDK": E:\Android development\sdk\tools
    "Ant_Home": C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4
    "JDK_Home": C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
```

Following the Win7 sys variables(**System variable**:)

```
    E:\Android development\nodejs\;E:\Android development\nodejs\package\Git\cmd; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin
```

**Update**

Ok, I've missed to install cordova properly...

Repeated the step after the commend line

```
    npm install -g cordova

    and getting the following message now:

    E:\Android development\nodejs\mmiapp>phonegap build local android

    C:\Users\Reen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\build.js:83

self.phonegap.emit('log', PG_STR.msgdet[0], platform.human, PG_STR.msgdet[
                                                    ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'human' of undefined at BuildCommand.execute (C:\Users\Reen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\build.js:83:57)
    at BuildCommand.run (C:\Users\Reen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\build.js:65:10)
    at PhoneGap.build (C:\Users\Reen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\util\command.js:28:25)
    at CLI.module.exports [as build] (C:\Users\Reen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\cli\build.js:35:14)
    at CLI.module.exports [as argv] (C:\Users\Reen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\cli\argv.js:66:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Reen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js:26:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

**Update from 2nd of June - 9:38 pm**
I just gave it a shot and tried to install ant with ndm via the cdm

```
    e:\Android development\nodejs\mmiapp>npm install -g apache ant
    
    npm WARN engine ant@0.2.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.8.0"} (current:
    {"node":"v0.10.29 ","npm":"1.4.14"})
    ant@0.2.0 C:\Users\Reen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ant`
```

Comment: can you simplify your code and description? too cumbersome

Comment: Cordova just sucks when it comes to clear error messages. The first error was due to you not having installed Apache Ant. Have you installed it? Secondly, have you created any android targets?

Comment: @ivarni: Yeah, especially for users that see it for the first time :S 


I did not install ant directly, but unzipped it to my local drive and added it into the path as the system variables (Sys configurations -> System -> Advanced sys options -> Sys path)

--> See my update on the initial question.

Comment: @ivarni if you mean with "android target the folder / the app path, yes I have it's in "nodejs/myapp". Otherwise I don't know what you mean. Sry **Newbe** here... :(

Comment: This kind of android target: http://verticalhorizons.in/creating-an-android-virtual-device-and-setting-up-android-emulator/

Comment: It is a shame the installation guide is so incomplete :/